# I need to read RFID tags data with Allflex RFID Reader in iOS app. What should i use for this in iOS or how to read this using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, rfid

Need to read EID tags with Allflex RFID reader. Can we read tag data using CoreBluetooth?Is there anything equivalent to BluetoothSocket in iOS like android?

Comment: Does the reader use BLE?  If so then you can probably use Core Bluetooth, but you will need information from the manufacturer on how to interface with the device. If it uses a legacy Bluetooth profile, such as SPP, then no, you can't use an iOS app to read the data.

Comment: A bit more research indicates that the rs420 reader is MFi compliant; in theory you can connect to it using the external accessory framework but you will need the manufacturer to authorise your app before you can put it in the store.